# Code not working after changing object to nested array

Tags: javascript, typescript

My code was working perfectly fine, until when der were only one `sections` item inside `areas`.

Now my data structure got changes, inside `areas` der can be multiple `sections` items.

Due to the structure change, I tried the below method,

```
function parseAreas() {
  data[0].areas.forEach(area => {
    this.moveToNewObject(area);
  })
}
```

Comment: Since you've tagged this "typescript", _please_ define and use some types and interfaces too!

Answer (score 0):

you have many mistakes in your code. for eg.

```
const sections = data.sections;
```

in your array you have `data->areas->sections`. but you have directly accessed `data.sections` which is undefined.

I have modified your code. please check if it solves your issue

```js
const data = {
  data: [{
    areas: [{
        sections: [{
          rjf: [{
              "type": "heading-1",
              "text": "A title",
            },
            {
              "type": "ordered-list-item",
              "text": "Ordered Item A",
            },
            {
              "type": "unordered-list-item",
              "text": "Ordered Item B",
            },
            {
              "type": "heading-1",
              "text": "A title",
            }
          ]
        }]
      },
      {
        sections: [{
          rjf: [{
              "type": "heading-1",
              "text": "Block 2 A title",
            },
            {
              "type": "ordered-list-item",
              "text": "Block 2 Ordered Item A",
            },
            {
              "type": "unordered-list-item",
              "text": "Block 2 Ordered Item B",
            },
            {
              "type": "heading-1",
              "text": "Block 2 A title",
            }
          ]
        }]
      }
    ]
  }]
};

function parseAreas() {
  data[0].areas.forEach(area => {
    this.moveToNewObject(area);
  })
}


function moveToNewObject(data) {
  const areas = data[0].areas;
  //console.log(data[0].areas)
  const listItemTypes = ['unordered-list-item', 'ordered-list-item'];
  return areas.map((area) => {
  var sec = area.sections;
  return sec.map((section) => {
    let lastHeadingIndex = -1;
    return section.rjf.reduce((acc, current, index) => {
      if (!current.type || !listItemTypes.includes(current.type)) {
        lastHeadingIndex = acc.length;
        return [...acc, current]
      } else {
        let listObject = acc.find((el, i) => i > lastHeadingIndex && i < index && el.type === 'list');
        if (!listObject) {
          listObject = {
            type: 'list',
            items: [current]
          }
          return [...acc, listObject];
        }
        listObject.items = [...listObject.items, current];
        return acc;
      }
    }, [])
  });
  });
}
console.log('sections', moveToNewObject(data.data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parse function needs to take `data` as a parameter or it will attempt to access the globally defined `data`. Let's also move your console.log statement inside that function or we will not see the output (alternatively, figure out a way to return all the output from `parseAreas`). Finally you actually need to call that method.

```
function parseAreas(data) {
  data[0].areas.forEach(area => {
    console.log('sections', JSON.stringify(moveToNewObject(area)));
  })
}

parseAreas(data.data)
```